# The getdata method in class file does not showing the output

Tags: asp.net

Here I declared `getdata` method() in class file account.vb. After clicking on `GET` button as a output it show the `msgbox` as 0 0.... so please help me:

**Default.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'declaring the obj of class account

    Dim obj As New account



    Protected Sub btn_create_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_create.Click

        'initializing the object obj on class accounts
        obj = New account



    End Sub


    Protected Sub btn_set_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_set.Click

        'sending the values from textboxes to accounts class through method setdata



        Try
            obj.setdata(CInt(txt_accno.Text), (txt_name.Text), CInt(txt_bal.Text))

            'obj.setdata(txt_accno.Text, txt_name.Text, txt_bal.Text)

            MsgBox("value are set")

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_get_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_get.Click

        'calling the method getdata to view the output


        Try

            obj.getdata()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

**Account.vb**

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class account

    Private accno As Integer
    Private acc_name As String
    Private bal As Integer


    'public method to populate above three private variable

    Public Sub setdata(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As String, ByVal c As Integer)
        Me.accno = a
        Me.acc_name = b
        Me.bal = c
    End Sub

    Public Sub getdata()
        MsgBox(Me.accno.ToString + vbNewLine + Me.acc_name + vbNewLine + Me.bal.ToString)
    End Sub

    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Obj in your page. whenever you click the button the Obj veriable reset as postback happens. You need to store the value of Obj. There are verious ways of storing it. ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application. HTTP is a stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each HTTP request for a page as an independent request. The server retains no knowledge of variable values that were used during previous requests. ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist variable values for the duration of that session. By default, ASP.NET session state is enabled for all ASP.NET applications.

So using session Obj object preserves and when you set and get data it remains on the page even if post back happens

try below code

```
Default.aspx.vb

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'declaring the obj of class account

    Dim obj As New account



    Protected Sub btn_create_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_create.Click

        'initializing the object obj on class accounts
        obj = New account

        session("ClsObj") = obj

    End Sub


    Protected Sub btn_set_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_set.Click

        'sending the values from textboxes to accounts class through method setdata



        Try
            obj = session("ClsObj")
            obj.setdata(CInt(txt_accno.Text), (txt_name.Text), CInt(txt_bal.Text))

            'obj.setdata(txt_accno.Text, txt_name.Text, txt_bal.Text)

            MsgBox("value are set")

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_get_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_get.Click

        'calling the method getdata to view the output


        Try
            obj = session("ClsObj")
            obj.getdata()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class

*************************************************
Account.vb

Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class account

    Private accno As Integer
    Private acc_name As String
    Private bal As Integer


    'public method to populate above three private variable

    Public Sub setdata(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As String, ByVal c As Integer)
        Me.accno = a
        Me.acc_name = b
        Me.bal = c
    End Sub

    Public Sub getdata()
        MsgBox(Me.accno.ToString + vbNewLine + Me.acc_name + vbNewLine + Me.bal.ToString)
    End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: yes.. it works.... can you please explain what is the meaning of the line  session("ClsObj") = obj......obj = session("ClsObj")

Comment: i am writing this in answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Protected Sub btn_create_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_create.Click
    Dim obj As New account
    obj = New account
    Session["obj"] = obj
End Sub

Protected Sub btn_set_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_set.Click
    Try
        Dim obj  as New account
        obj = CType(Session["obj"], account)
        obj.setdata(CInt(txt_accno.Text), (txt_name.Text), CInt(txt_bal.Text))
        MsgBox("value are set")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub btn_get_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_get.Click
    Try
        Dim obj  as New account
        obj = CType(Session["obj"], account)
        obj.getdata()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```